# getOutputStream() has already been called Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc

Our requirement is to download files from FTP server which we used a download files in sequential manner one after another which is taking huge time.

Sequential code:

```
for(String mediaValue: generatedMediaTypes) {
    // Logic here is getting the user selected files from Ui and keep it in string array str
    try {
        ddownloadMultipleNavDbs(str[i]),uniqueID);
        //now we download all the files here with downloadfile logic with help of unique id we are a folder by that name and keep all this files in that folder
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

After downloading all files into uniqueID folder now I zip and send to client by `downloadZip(request,uniqueID)`:

```
public void downloadZipFile (HttpServletResponse response, String suuid) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");

        File loadableFolder = new File(uniqueID);

        String timeStamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()).toString().replaceAll(
                "-", "_").replaceAll(" ", "_").replaceAll(":", "_");

        response.setHeader(
                "Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + "File" + timeStamp.substring(
                        0, timeStamp.indexOf(".")) + ".ZIP");

        File[] loadableMedias = //here we get the files from that uinqueID folder

        ZipUtil.addFilesToZipStream(Medias, Folder,
                zipOutputStream);

        zipOutputStream.close();

        response.flushBuffer();
         response.getOutputStream().flush();
         response.getOutputStream().close();
    }
```

It works perfectly fine in above code.
When I used executorservice for downloading files in parallel

```
executorService.submit(new myThread(str[i]),uniqueID);
```

am facing error:

> getOutputStream() has already been closed

Can anyone please explain me why am facing this error?

Why we face this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Please help me with good solution.am struggling with it since a week..and not returing anything to view or jsp

Comment: With executor service your output stream is closed by one of thread which gets completed first and when second thread tries to write to it, the exception is thrown, in order to avoid this you need to only close the stream when all the files have been written or if any exception occurs

Comment: all the output streams are closed properly still am getting this error

Comment: Improved syntax formatting

Comment: you are actually referring to same output stream in different threads and that is why you are getting exception.

Comment: after all files are downloaded with that unique id path am calling downloadZip method...all threads will be destroyed at this time..i only call outputstream one time

Comment: Show your `myThread` class.

Comment: class myThread implements Runnable { 
 //getting all variable here and using in method
  public void run() {
   try {
    
    downloadMultipleNavDbs(string, parseInt, blueCD, parseInt2, string2, mediaType, null, suuid);
   } catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("____________-------------------------------------------------------");
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

 }